# selection of radio button inside a modal pop-up

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a modal that pop-up upon a button click which has two radio buttons with same input name "radioButtons".

Radio button 1 --> (is checked by default)

```
   <input class="form-checks" type="radio" name="radioButtons" value="1" checked="checked">
```

Radio button 2 -->

```
<input class="form-checks" type="radio" name="radioButtons" value="2">
```

I have tried using the following code in the console in order to see which button is selected:

```
$("input[name='radioButtons']:selected").val() --> returns 1
```

**Problem**: It "ALWAYS" return 1 even when the selection has changed to radio button 2. I need to know the selection as I have some logic to be written on top of this selection.

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For radio buttons you need to use `:checked` instead of `:selected`

```js
$("[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
  $("label").text($("input[name='radioButtons']:checked").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Radio button 1 -->

<input class="form-checks" type="radio" name="radioButtons" value="1" checked="checked">
<br/> Radio button 2 -->

<input class="form-checks" type="radio" name="radioButtons" value="2">
<br/> Selected:
<label></label>
```

Comment: *EDIT* -- I used $("input[name='radioButtons']:checked").val() and still running into the same issue. FYI- I need the selected value on Modal Load AND on change , not just on change, which is becoming a little trickier than I imagined! Any inputs?

Comment: I kind of wrote an extra if condition inside my js function & looks like the problem is solved! I will still mark your answer as the most appropriate one. Thanks much!